# Power BI web schedule refresh doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, powerbi, refresh, dashboard

I connected my PostgreSQL DB to Power BI and then built a dashboard. Now I want to refresh the dashboard automatically once a day. I saw that there is an option to do that using the Power BI web version, so I have published the dashboard. In addition, I have pinned the report to the live view option. Then, I have determined the schedule refresh and added a new row to the DB. After the refresh time passed, nothing happened. I pressed the Refresh button in the Power BI web version, and still, nothing happened. However, when I went back to the Power BI desktop application and pressed the refresh button, the dashboard did refresh.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PostgreSQL database is installed on-premise and Power BI Online server, which runs in the cloud, can't connect to your database, which runs in your internal network. 
You need to install [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) to allow Power BI to connect to your database, and [configure it](http://niftit.com/installing-power-bi-data-gateway-refresh-postgresql-database/).

Answer (score 0):

Your Power BI app is pulling data right from the source. The on-line web version requires a data gateway, either personal or on-prem depending on your business needs. Remember you can only use live refresh with a single source.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/